# Создание списка из NSView с xib как в Twitter for Mac, Echofon, Mail.app (Lion)

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, mac

Вот хочу сделать список типа как в Twitter for Mac, Echofon, Mail.app (Lion)... В iPhone это просто делается на основе таблици с кастомной ячейкой из вьюшки. А тут же как-то сразу нет очевидного решения. В таблицу нельзя загнать вьюшку.

Нашел интересный компонент [PXListView](https://github.com/nonamelive/PXListView).

Но он странно работает. Половину функционала пришлось вырезать. А когда пытаюсь удалять строки снизу вверх, то пропадают все ячейки и появляются только после перезагрузки таблицы.

Посоветуйте еще способ создания списка из массива по заданному шаблону в  XIB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSCollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Руководство [тут](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030) или [вот тут](http://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/nscollectionview-tutorial-for-dummies-xcode-3-1-3/).

Comment: Да, и если вы собираетесь писать приложение под Lion - там появилась поддержка view-based содержимого ячеек (как на iOS) для NSTableView.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо. Я все рылся в таблицах, а оказалось все так просто.

Comment: Да я сам когда этим делом занимался по началу рисовал кастомные NSCell'ы для NSTableView. Получалось криво, но хоть как-то работало. И только дня через 2 до меня дошло, что можно и на другие варианты посмотреть.